# Confidence intervals assume that the $t$-statistic is normally distributed. What if we don't assume this?

Tags: statistics

#### Introduction

The logic behind confidence intervals is like this:

The $t$-statistic $\frac{\bar{X} -\mu}{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}$ approaches $N(0,1)$ in distribution. (This is a corollary of the Central Limit Theorem.) If our $n$ is big enough (usually $\geq 40$), we may assume that the $t$-statistic *does* follow a $N(0,1)$ distribution. In that case:

$$P(-z_{0.025}\leq\frac{\bar{X} -\mu}{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}\leq z_{0.025})=0.95$$
and therefore:
$$P(\mu \in [\bar X - z_{0.025}\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}},\bar X + z_{0.025}\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}])=0.95$$

But by the Central Limit Theorem, $\frac{\bar{X} -\mu}{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}$ only approaches $N(0,1)$ in distribution...! We have no idea whether it is reasonable to assume that it itself follows a normal distribution.

#### Question

Is there an approach to confidence intervals that takes into account how much $\frac{\bar{X} -\mu}{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}$ might deviate from a standard normal distribution?

Answer (score 1):

First, the $t-$interval is *exact* if $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$. Otherwise, we rely on asymptotic theory. If you doubt this, then you can go with bootstrapping to estimate the distribution of the sample statistic about your target functional (usually the mean).

Answer (score 0):

**Small normal sample.** If your data are normal and the sample size is small, then 
$T = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{S/\sqrt{n}}$ is not normal, but
follows Student's t distribution with $\nu = n-1$ degrees of freedom.
The confidence interval is of the form $\bar X \pm t^*S/\sqrt{n},$
where you can get the appropriate value $t^*$ from the row of a
t table with $\nu$ degrees of freedom. (For example, if $n = 10,$
then $\nu = 9$ and $t^* = 2.262$ for a 95% confidence interval.)

**Sample from unknown distribution.** If your data are not normal (and you do not know the population distribution) you may want to use a nonparametric
test based on ranks, such as a Wilcoxon signed-rank test, to get
a confidence interval for the population *median* $\eta.$ Alternatively,
as @Bey suggests (+1), you might use a bootstrap procedure to get an approximate
confidence interval for the population mean $\mu.$
(Also, there is good evidence that if the population distribution is
not very much different from normal, a confidence interval based on
the t distribution might be accurate enough for many practical purposes.)

**Sample from known non-normal distribution.** If your data are from a known distribution other than normal, there
may be a different kind confidence interval for the population mean $\mu.$
For example, if data are exponential, then the sample mean has
a gamma distribution, and that can be used to make a confidence interval.
(Mathematical statistics books are full of nice exercises in which one
is asked to find a confidence interval for a data from a *particular*
kind of non-normal distribution.)

*Note:* To be specific about CIs for exponential data, suppose
$X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{10}$ is a random sample of size $n = 10$ from
$\mathsf{Exp}(rate=1/\mu),$ so that $E(X_i) = \mu.$

Then 
$\bar X/\mu \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(shape=n,rate=n),$ and
$$P(.4795 \le \bar X/\mu \le 1.7085) = P(\bar X/1.7085 \le \mu \le \bar X/.4795) = 0.95.$$
Thus $(\bar X/1.7085,\, \bar X/.4795)$ is a 95% CI for $\mu.$
Because the exponential distribution is not symmetrical, this CI contains $\bar X,$ but is not symmetrical about $\bar X.$ [If the mean of ten exponential 
observations is $\bar X = 2.34,$ then a 95% CI for $\mu$ is $(1.37,\,4.88)$.]

The required quantiles of the gamma distribution can be obtained using software;
in R statistical software:

```
qgamma(c(.025,.975),10,10)
## 0.4795389 1.7084803
```

Or with a little trickery, tables of the chi-squared distribution could also be used; see [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)
 (under 'Confidence Intervals'):

```
qchisq(c(.025,.975),20)/20
## 0.4795389 1.7084803
```